# The fatal error after running the tshark.c source file on the second time

Tags: c++, c, wireshark, tshark, wireshark-dissector

I want to run *Tshark dissector* from the source file (i.e. `tshark.c` which is writen in *C* language) instead of using terminal and the following command:

```
tshark -r my.pcap ...
```

So I changed `tshark.c` main funtion from:

```
int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  return real_main(argc, argv);
}
```

to:

```
int
tshark_main(char arg0[],char arg1[],char arg2[],char arg3[],char arg4[],char arg5[],char arg6[],char arg7[])
{
    int argc=8;
    char* const  argv[] = {arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7,NULL};
    return (real_main(argc, argv));
}
```

in order to call the main function from another functions. After that I 
created a lib consist of `tshark.c` and other dependecies and made the required include file as follows:

```
#ifndef __TSHARK_H__
#define __TSHARK_H__

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif /* __cplusplus */

#ifdef _WIN32
int
wmain(int argc, wchar_t *wc_argv[]);
#else
int
tshark_main(char arg0[], char arg1[], char arg2[], char arg3[], char arg4[], char arg5[], char arg6[], char arg7[]);
#endif


#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif /* __cplusplus */

#endif /* tshark.h */
```

In the next step, I added the mentioned lib and `*.h` file to my *C++* project and call the tshark_main function as follows:

```
char arg0[]="";
char arg1[]="-o";
char arg2[]="uat:user_dlts:\"User 0 (DLT=147)\",\"RRC.SI.SIB1\",\"0\",\"\",\"0\",\"\"";
char arg3[]="-r";
char arg4[]="my1.pcap";
char arg5[]="-V";
char arg6[]="";
char arg7[]="";
tshark_main(arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7);
char arg4[]="my2.pcap";
tshark_main(arg0,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4,arg5,arg6,arg7);
```

But, in `tshark_main(...)` second call (last line) a fatal error appears like this:

```
** (process:8445): ERROR **: 18:05:33.070: file type short name already exists
```

I think this error is because of the static variables that is defined in the source file(s) and when I call the `tshark_main(...)` for the first time every thing is OK and when I call that in second or more times, the variables have changed. As *Wireshark* can dissect the packets and files over and over, So I need an initialization method or some thing like that which *wireshark* uses to reset the static variables but I don't know where it is. Also, There may be a second way to reset every thing before calling `tshark_main(...)` for the second time which I don't know how to do it. Can every one tell me the solution?

Comment: Obviously this is not what you did, as this cannot compile.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher First I created a C project and compiled that with C compiler and created a lib. Second I created a C++ project and added that lib to it with *.h file which I made. After that I compiled my C++ project with C++ compiler.

Comment: @rustyx thanks, I know that where this error appears. It comes from [https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/master/wiretap/file_access.c#L2036] where `wtap_num_file_types_subtypes` in `for` loop should be 81 but in second time it is 82 and `dump_open_table[81].short_name` is illegal access (because `dump_open_table` size is 81 and max of `dump_open_table` element index is 80). What is the correct invocation?

Comment: @rustyx Can you give more guidance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct invocation?

The correct invocation is not to try to run the main function twice, as it'll try to register the file type readers twice, and give you the error message in question.

That's the same question as [this ask.wireshark.org](https://ask.wireshark.org/question/7697/my-modified-tshark-fails-with-file-type-short-name-already-exists/) question, and the answer is the same.

Comment: thanks, the link which you mentioned is my question in **Wireshark** community.